# Unity ScriptableObject with reference to ScriptableObject passed to a Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, software-design

So I've got A Data Script:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName="MyData", fileName="GoData")]
public class MyData : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> myObjects;

    public List<GameObject> MyObjects { get { return myObjects; } }
}
```

which is simply a container for a bunch of gameobjects. this container is supposed to be passed into a scriptableobject like this:

```
public class SomeAwesomeScript : ScriptableObject, ISomeAwesomeInterface
{
    public MyData myData;

    public SomeAwesomeScript Init(...)
    {
        //initializations, since we cant use constructors when using ScriptableObject
    }

    public void DoSomeAwesomeShit()
    {
        DoSomethingWith(myData.MyObjects);
    }
}
```

now the `DoSomeAwesomeShit` is defined in the `ISomeAwesomeInterface` and the actual implementation is supposed to be unique to every other class that implements this method.

The SomeAwesomeScript is then used within a monobehaviour like this:

```
public class SomeAwesomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ISomeAwesomeInterface awesomeness;

    void Start()
    {
        //initialising awesomeness
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //...
        awesomeness.DoSomeAwesomeShit();
        //some code, changing awesomeness to other ISomeAwesomeInterface based on some condition maybe
    }
}
```

The issue here is that i cant assign `MyData` to `SomeAwesomeScript` because
`Default references will only be applied in edit mode`
Because of that MyData is null when i start the unity program.

Is there a way to solve this? or am i forced to hardcode the "MyData" part into every ISomeAwesomeInterface

EDIT:

Those Scripts do not have to inherit ScriptableObject

The only reason i did this design right here, is because i need to assign List to my SomeAwesomeScript (and every other implementation of ISomeAwesomeInterface) and there didnt seem to be any way other than to make those scripts inherit ScriptableObject

Comment: Why are you separating MyData from your scriptableobject ? You can create assetsmenu for SO. And of course you CAN use methods like your Init() in a scriptable object. SO are exactly like monobehaviour, but not linked to a gameobject

Comment: I want to have a indefiite ammount of scripts implementing ISomeAwesomeInterface, each with a different behaviour. every of those ISomeAwesomeInterface-Scripts will have different Data aswell. thats why i tried to seperate the data out. And i do not want to create a assetmenu for SomeAwesomeScript, because i want to have a method later in them, in which they can return their "next" (similar to the way a linkedlist does with its item)

Comment: This looks a lot like what I did with my dialogueManager. each dialogue is a SO, and have a next dialogue that just links another SO and there is no problem. Why having MyData into SoemAwesomeScript makes it that you can't create another class implementing ISomeblabla ? I don't really understand

Comment: And why isn't MyData a scriptableobject aswell ? I'm pretty sure you can't create an asset that is just a plain c# class

Comment: typo, mydata is a scriptableobject

Comment: I want to have 5 different "MyData" and 5 different "SomeAwesomeScript", each MyData belonging to a single SomeAwesomeScript.

Comment: Yeah, and this is why you need to create 5 MyData assets, and 5 SomeAwesomeScript asset (hence the need to have an assetmenu), then just link them by dragging in the editor. I don't really understand the problem here lol

Comment: My bad. what i meant was not 5 different "SomeAwesomeScript", but 5 different "ISomeAwesomeInterface" implementations. so i would have something like "SomeAwesomeScript", "SomeDifferentAwesomeScript", "SomeScript", "SomeNewScript" and "SomeUniqueScript" all implementing "ISomeAwesomeInterface" and each one of those completely different scripts is supposed to have a different "MyData"

Comment: and for that i already created MyData Assets. but when assigning them to the scripts they become null

Comment: But then, what are your "SomeScriptXXX" ? If they are SO that are assets within your assets folder, you can just grab your MyData assets into the myData variable in the editor. I'm doing just that

Comment: They are no assets. they are supposed to be scripts that do stuff. right now they are dynamically initialized from a different script. it would be very hardcody if i would just create assets for every new implementation and drag them into another script. this would just defeat the whole purpose of me using OOP there (i think)

Comment: But ScriptableObjects ARE assets, that you create and instantiate before runtime. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html

Comment: ok then. the SomeAwesomeScript doesnt have to be a scriptableobject. i made them SO's because i wanted to drag the MyData into them, because i can't see a alternative way to assign a default value for List<GameObject>

Comment: I don't know your use case, but what you could do is have a monobehaviour like MyDataReferences as a singleton, having all your myData as public variables, and then you could get your mydata using MyDataReference.Instance.myData1

Comment: By the default references you seem to mean you dragged it into the reference of the script file itself. Rather reference the according object in an **instance** of `SomeAwesomeScript` .. this should work without problems.

Comment: ye i dragged it into the script itself. and dragging it into the script itself doesnt work. creating a instance first and then dragging it should work. im gonna try something